# Dynamic custom mediator parametres in wso2 ESB

Tags: wso2, esb, mediator

I built custom mediator using articles http://wso2.com/library/2898/ and http://wso2.com/library/2936/ .

It looks like this:

```
<inSequence>
  <property expression="local-name($body/*[1])" name="method" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
  <MyMediator>
     <header>SomeHeader<header/>
     <topic>SomeTopic</topic>
  </MyMediator>
</inSequence>
```

It works well, but one issue I didn't solve, how I can dynamically change value of header and/or topic mediators parameter?

When I tried to put something like `get-property('method')` instead of `SomeHeader`. It was delivered into mediator code like string, ebs didn't calculate it.

My question is how to change value of my custom mediators parameter to property value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose for exemple to use {} braces to say that your string is an XPath request. In your mediator, if you find {} in first and last position, use org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath : create a new SynapseXPath with your xpath (the string between {}) and use stringValueOf(theMessageContext)

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass any dynamic value to a custom mediator, but you can read any property within custom mediators.

```
public boolean mediate(MessageContext mc) {
   String value = (String) mc.getProperty("SomeHeader");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Current implementation doesn't support for expressions as class mediator properties. Please refer [Jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4875) for more details.